# Two light sources are a distance D apart. Show that in an inertial frame O' the photons are separated by a constant distance

Tags: special-relativity

Two light sources are at rest and at a distance D apart on the x-axis of some inertial frame, O. They emit photons simultaneously in that frame in the positive x-direction. Show that in an inertial frame, O', in which the sources have a velocity v along the x-axis, the photons are separated by a constant distance $$D\sqrt{\frac{c-u}{c+u}}$$

I let E1 be the event where source 1 emits the photon and E2 for the second source with the respective coordinates in O as $(x_1, t_1$) and $(x_2,t_2)$ such that $t_2=t_1 \because$ simultaneous and $x_2-x_1 =D$.

Using Lorentz transformation I obtained that in O', $$x'_2-x'_1 = \gamma (D-v(t_2-t_1))=\gamma D \ \because t_2 = t_1$$ In the solutions $t_2-t_1 = \frac{D}{c} $ however I cannot see where this came from.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in $O$, if the photons have wavelength $\lambda$, then the number of cycles (of phase) between the two photons is:

$$ N = D/\lambda $$

Since $N$ is a Lorentz invariant and the Doppler shift says:

$$ \lambda' = \sqrt{\frac{c-v}{c+v}} $$

then:

$$ D' = D\sqrt{\frac{c-v}{c+v}} $$

So that *is* the correct answer.

If you set the $O$ origin so that

$$x_1 = 0$$
$$x_2 = D$$
$$t_1 = t_2 = 0$$

and make the $O'$ origin the same event as the $O$ origin:

$$ x_1' = 0$$
$$ x_2' = \gamma D$$
$$ t_1' = 0$$
$$ t_2' = \gamma(0-\frac{vD}{c^2}) = -\gamma   \frac{vD}{c^2} $$

so that $E_2$ occurs before $E_1$ in $O'$.

If you add that "head-start" onto $x_2'-x_1'$:

$$ D' = (x_2'-x_1') + c(t_2' - t_1') $$
$$ D' = (\gamma D) + c(-\gamma   \frac{vD}{c^2})$$
$$ D' = D(\gamma -\gamma\frac{v}{c}) = \gamma D(1-\frac v c)$$
$$ D' = D\frac{1-v/c}{\sqrt{(1-v/c)(1+v/c)}} = D\sqrt{\frac{c-v}{c+v}} $$

So that is the position of the "2" photon when the "1" photon is emitted in $O'$:

$$ (t', x')_{O'} = (0, D')_{O'} $$

It is *not* the same as $t'_2$.